# Not able to retrieve data with .getJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am new to JSON and jQuery, and am currently having an issue retrieving data from a JSON file into a javascript file that is using a `.getJSON()` function. I don't believe what I've coded is correct, and I don't know what to change. Both files are in the same folder, and this is all being run over XAMPP. My current `.getJSON` function is:

```
var url = 'http://localhost/atriviagame/database.json';
$.getJSON(url, function(json) {    
  var questions = json.questions;
});
```

And my current JSON file is:

```
 {
    "questions": [{
        "question": "Which list contains words that are NOT names of shoe types:",
        "choices": ["A. Oxford, jelly, boat, clogs, stiletto, mary jane",
            "B. Loafer, gladiator, wedge, mule, platform",
            "C. Pump, moccasin, wingtip, sneaker, derby, monk",
            "D. Chalupa, dogler, hamster, croonley, frankfurt",
            " "
        ],
        "correctAnswer": 3
    }]
}
```

Comment: [JSONLint - The JSON Validator](https://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: `http:localhost` isn't a thing.  `http://localhost` is though. You can use something like this too - to ensure your problem isn't fetching local data: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/

Comment: Just to follow up on adeneo's comment. If you run the json you have posted in the snippet thru the validator it shows your json is invalid which is no good.

Comment: The function will currently not show any real feedback either.

Comment: Can you go into some further detail sheriffderek?

Comment: also consider opening your browser developer tools, it can help see the actual errors with your ajax calls